# Need help to find average, min and max values in shell script from text file (again)

Tags: bash, shell

This is an update to a question I posted before. I've gotten a little farther into this but need help with a new problem.

I'm working on a shell script right now. I need to loop through a text file, grab the text from it, and find the average number, max number and min number from each line of numbers then print them in a chart with the name of each line. This is the text file:

```
Experiment1 9 8 1 2 9 0 2 3 4 5
collect1 83 39 84 2 1 3 0 9
jump1 82 -1 9 26 8 9
exp2 22 0 7 1 0 7 3 2
jump2 88 7 6 5
taker1 5 5 44 2 3
```

This is my code so far. It should be working but it won't do any of the calculations. First loop grabs the line of text, second loop separates the name from the numbers, these two work. tHe thrid loop takes the numbers and does the calculations. It keeps giving me an error saying "expr: non integer argument", why is it doing that? I shouldn't

```
#!/bin/bash


while read line
do 
echo $line | while read first second 
  do
    echo $first
    echo $second
    sum=0
    max=0
    min=0
    len=0
    for arg in $second
    do
      sum=`expr $sum + $arg`
      if [ $min > $arg ]
      then
        set min=$arg
      fi
      if [ $max < $arg ]
      then
        set max=$arg
      fi
      len=`expr $len + 1`
    done
    avg=`expr $sum / $len`
    echo $avg
    echo $min
    echo $max
  done
done < mystats.txt
```

This is the desired output when you type "bash statcalc.sh -s name mystats.txt"

```
Experiment Name Average Max Min
collect1        27      84  0
exp2            5       22  0
Experiment1     3       9   0
jump1           21      82  -1
jump2           31      88  5
taker1          13      44  2
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: On the other hand, congratulations, you just created (if it does not exists or truncated if it does) a bunch/series of text files in your current directory from the input file. because of the `[ .... > .... ]`

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

`awk '{if (NR==1)print "Experiment Name Average Max Min"; min=$2;max=$2;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {a[$1]=a[$1]+$i; if (min<$i) min=$i; if(max>$i)max=$i} print $1, int(a[$1]/(NF-1)),min,max}'`

Demo :

```
$awk '{if (NR==1)print "Experiment Name Average Max Min"; min=$2;max=$2;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {a[$1]=a[$1]+$i; if (min<$i) min=$i; if(max>$i)max=$i} print $1, int(a[$1]/(NF-1)),min,max}'  file.txt | column -t
Experiment   Name  Average  Max  Min
Experiment1  4     9        0
collect1     27    84       0
jump1        22    82       -1
exp2         5     22       0
jump2        26    88       5
taker1       11    44       2


$cat file.txt 
Experiment1 9 8 1 2 9 0 2 3 4 5
collect1 83 39 84 2 1 3 0 9
jump1 82 -1 9 26 8 9
exp2 22 0 7 1 0 7 3 2
jump2 88 7 6 5
taker1 5 5 44 2 3
$
```